# Flask session not persisting

Tags: python, session, flask

Am running with Python 2.7, Apache + mod_wsgi on CentOS 6.3

Things work fine when I am on localhost. However, when I run the code on a vm in Azure, I do not see the session information being persisted across pages.

Basically in my views, I have something like:

```
@frontend.route('/')
def index():
   session['foo'] = 'bar'
   print session['foo']

   return redirect(url_for("frontend.page2"))

@frontend.route('page2')
def page2():
   print session
```

The print output is:

```
bar
<SecureCookieSession {}>
```

My wsgi configuration for apache is:

```
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess myproj threads=5 processes=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/mydir/myproj/apache/myproj.wsgi

    <Directory /home/mydir/myproj>
        WSGIScriptReloading On
        WSGIProcessGroup myproj
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have the secret_key set:

```
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)
```

I have tried with both setting SERVER_NAME but it doesn't help:

```
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'example.com'
```

Any ideas on how I can debug this more?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a secret key? It's required for sessions: `app.secret_key = 'something long and random'`

Comment: Yes I have secret key. Thx.

Comment: Where do you store your sessions?

Comment: @cababunga: I was using Flask's default storage. The problem is fixed, it was the issue mata pointed out.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Don't use `app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)`!

You're supposed to enter a static value here, not read from `os.urandom` each time. You've probably misunderstood the example in the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#sessions), it shows you how you can read random data from `os.urandom`, but it also clearly states:

> Just take that thing and copy/paste it into your code and you’re done

If you read it at runtime, then each of your worker processes will have a different secret key! That means if a request is handled by a different worker, the session will break because the cookie is signed with the wrong secret key.

Comment: Doh, that was it. Thanks much. Wish this was more obvious to debug.