# How session is passed to templates and between functions of the app, in Flask?

Tags: python, session, flask, proxy

During investigation of [another conundrum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949860/session-key-is-not-modified-from-flask-tests) that I had with Flask sessions, I have tried to better my understanding of how Flask sessions work, in general.

---

According to [Flask documentation on sessions](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/api/#flask.session) `session` object itself is a [proxy](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/reqcontext/#notes-on-proxies).

My understanding *(that is, in all probability, wrong in some way, and this is what this question is about =)* of what it means is:

1. the proxy `session` object is accessed from the app and is used to modify read data as needed
2. normally, proxy-`session` will transfer it's changes to proxied-`session` right away *(except for the [change of mutables](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/api/#flask.session.modified) in proxy-`session`)*
3. in case if proxied-`session` is busy (in case of a multi-thread app), proxy-`session` will wait until proxied-`session` available, and then transfer it's changes to proxied-`session`
4. templates receive the 'original' session (i.e. proxied-`session`), so there is no ability/need to access `session._get_current_object()` from the templates
5. as dictionaries (which `session` is) are mutable, I'd assume it's id should remain unchanged for the length of session (though content could be modified)
6. the actual `session` (proxied object, that is available via `session._get_current_object()`) should never change its `ID`

Now, when I have tried to check my assumptions - the behaviour I've encountered confused me a bit.

Consider the following code:

***my_app.py***

```python
from flask import (
Flask,
render_template,
session,
)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'some random secret key'

@app.route('/create/')
def create():
    session['example'] = ['one', 'two']
    print_ids()
    return str(session['example'])

@app.route('/modify/')
def modify():
    session['example'].append('three')
    print_ids()
    return render_template('my_template.html', id=id)

@app.route('/display/')
def display():
    print_ids()
    return str(session['example'])

def print_ids():
    import inspect
    calling_function = inspect.stack()[1][3]
    print('')
    print(calling_function + ": session ID is: {}".format(id(session)))
    print(calling_function + ": session['example'] ID is {}".format(id(session['example'])))
    print('________________________________')
    print(calling_function + ": session._get_current_object() ID is: {}".format(id(session._get_current_object())))
    print(calling_function + ": session._get_current_object()['example'] ID is: {}".format(id(session._get_current_object()['example'])))
```

***my_template.html***

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head><title>Display session['example']</title></head>
    <body>
        <div>
            {% if session['example'] %}
                {{ session['example'] }}
                <br />
                session ID is: {{ id(session) }}
                <br />
                session['example'] ID is: {{ id(session['example']) }}
                <br />
            {% else %}
                session['example'] is not set =(
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The idea is to print id's of proxy-`session`, `session['example']` (which is a list), proxied-`session` (i.e. `session._get_current_object()`) and proxied-`session['example']` (i.e. `session._get_current_object()['example']`) from every function, as well as `id(session)` and `id(session['example'])` on the rendered template, in order to track down what is used where.

Here are the results:

```python
.../create/
    # id(session)                                 4338311808 
    # id(session._get_current_object())           4343709776
    # id(session['example'])                                 4343654376
    # id(session._get_current_object()['example'])           4343654376

.../modify/
    # id(session)                                  4338311808
    # id(session._get_current_object())            4344315984
    # id(session['example'])                                  4343652720      
    # id(session._get_current_object()['example'])            4343652720
rendered my_template.html
    # id(session)                                  4344315984
    # id(session['example'])                                  4343652720

.../display/
    # id(session)                                  4338311808         
    # id(session._get_current_object())            4344471632
    # id(session['example'])                                  4341829576
    # id(session._get_current_object()['example'])            4341829576

# one more time
.../display/
    # id(session)                                  4338311808         
    # id(session._get_current_object())            4344471632
    # id(session['example'])                                  4344378072
    # id(session._get_current_object()['example'])            4344378072
```

Things I'm striving to understand are:

1. What are my misunderstandings/wrong assumptions, concerning Flask sessions concept, in general?
2. Why ids of `session['example']` and `session._get_current_object()['example']` are changed on every hit of display *(and every other method, but display in particular, since it does not modify anything, I would expect all ids to remain unchanged)*?
3. Why id of `session._get_current_object()` changes and id of `session` is not?
4. Since ids of `session['example']` and `session._get_current_object()['example']` are identical in context of any function, I would assume that if one object is changed - then both are changed, as they are the same object.

   With that being said, and taking into account that `session._get_current_object()['example']` is inside proxied (i.e. 'real') `session` I'd expect the following:

```python
    .../create/ # return ['one', 'two']
    .../modify/ # will render page containing ['one', 'two', 'three']
    .../display/ # return ['one', 'two', 'three'] as proxy and proxied sessions should have been modified
```

But as [I have previously discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46949861/8554766) - it's not happening. So why ids are the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of your confusion comes from misunderstandings about Flask proxy objects, such as `session`, `g` and `request`.

All that these objects do is make sure you get the correct data for the current thread; they proxy between a global object (accessible by all threads, easy to import and use in your Flask code), to an object stored in [thread-local storage](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-local-data), which is an object that transparently differentiates attribute access by thread id. There is no need for locking or 'waiting' in this, proxied objects are never used by more than one thread. `session.foo` indirectly accesses and returns the exact same object as `session._get_current_object().foo` does (which is why their ids always match).

So when accessing the `session` object, proxying is *transparent*. This is not something you ever need worry about unless you want to share a proxied object with another thread.

The proxied object you access is created a-new *for every request*. That's because the contents of a session are dependent on data in each request. Flask's session machinery is pluggable, but the default implementation stores all data in a cryptographically signed cookie, which needs to be decoded into Python data if you want to be able to interact with it. Each of your `/create/`, `/modify/` and `/display/` URLs are handled as separate requests, so they all load session data from your request into new Python objects; their ids will usually differ.

After a request is done, the session object is gone again. You can't have this any other way, because a new request coming in on the same thread needs to present the session data from that new request to your Flask code, not the data from the old request.

All this means that the output of `id()` is **meaningless** here. `id()` is a number that is unique for all currently **active** objects in the current Python process. This means that the ids of objects that are removed from memory can be reused, just because you have seen the same `id()` value at two points in time doesn't mean you have the same object. And just because you have the same *data* (value equality) doesn't mean that you have the same object in memory, even if their id is the same. The old object could have been deleted and a new object could simply have been re-created with the same value.

Under the hood, Flask calls the [`open_session()` method](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.sessions.SessionInterface.open_session) on the object assigned to [`Flask().session_interface`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.session_interface) at the start of each request. At the end, the [`save_session()` method](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.sessions.SessionInterface.save_session) is called to save the session again, and the session object is discarded. The default implementation is the [`SecureSessionInterface` object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.sessions.SecureCookieSessionInterface), which looks for a specific cookie on the request, and if present and with a valid signature, decodes the data as tagged JSON (a compact JSON serialisation), and returns a [`SecureCookieSession` instance](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.sessions.SecureCookieSession) with that data. This is the object that `session` proxies for, and is returned by `session._get_current_object()`. When saving, the data is serialised to tagged JSON again, signed, and added to the response as an outgoing `Set-Cookie` header.

Saving only happens when the session object has been 'changed', (`session.modified` is set to `True`). Note that the default implementation only sets `modified` to `True` when directly manipulating the session mapping (setting, updating or deleting keys in the mapping itself), not when changing mutable objects stored in the session; `session['foo'] = 'bar'` is detectable, but if you stored a list or dictionary in the session, then mutating those with expressions like `session['spam'][0] = 'ham'` will not be detected. Either re-set the mutable object (`session[key] = session[key]`) or set the `modified` flag to `True` manually.

Comment: Thanks a lot, of such a detailed answer! I especially thankful for elaborate explanation of the meaninglessness of `id()` values, in the context of the question.

Answer (score 3):

**Dedication =)**: this answer only came to be thanks to users: [brunns](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1073696/brunns) and [shmee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4134674/shmee) and their answers: [1(brunns)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55758011/8554766), [2(shmee)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55809062/8554766) to my other questions.

---

Here are answers to the list of ([my own](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)) questions:

1. The main blunder is that: yes — `session` is a proxy, yes — object proxied by `session` is returned by `session._get_current_object()`, **BUT:** **object proxied by `session` is different for every request**.
2. It is because object proxied by `session` (and thus everything it contains) is different for each request. For details: see answer to point 3, below.
3. Well:

   - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55758011/8554766) pointed out to me that, as `session` is an object imported from the `flask` module and as it is imported only once — its `id()` does not ever change
   - there is one underlying object (which is returned by `session._get_current_object()`) per request, and as suggested by [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55809062/8554766) to another question, as well as in [Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/reqcontext/#lifetime-of-the-context) — object proxied by `session` belongs to `RequestContext` and thus is different for each new request. Hence, different values for different requests (the only obscurity here is that **sometimes** `session._get_current_object()` remains unchanged between between consecutive requests, and as pointed out in the same [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55809062/8554766) (*bold is mine*), it is:

     > **probably**, due to the new session object being created in the same memory address that the old one from the previous request occupied.
4. Here the expectations are wrong — not the results. The reason `session['example']` is not modified from one request to another is clearly stated in the [documentation on `modified` attribute of a `session`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.session.modified):

   > Be advised that modifications on mutable structures are not picked up
   >   automatically, in that situation you have to explicitly set the
   >   attribute to `True` yourself.

   As `session['example']` is a [list](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) and lists are [mutable](https://docs.python.org/3.7/glossary.html#term-mutable) — in order changes to be picked up, we need to change the code for `modify` function, as follows:

   ```python
   @app.route('/modify/')
   def modify():
       session['example'].append('three')
       session.modified = True
       print_ids()
       return render_template('my_template.html', id=id)
   ```

   After this change:

   ```python
   .../create/ # returns ['one', 'two']
   .../modify/ # renders page containing ['one', 'two', 'three']
   .../display/ # returns ['one', 'two', 'three']
   ```